# Fast inter-row computation with Spark on grouped data

Tags: python, apache-spark

I've got a CSV file (> 3GB) of the following structure

```
groupId | time | value
1            0       2 
1            1       1 
1            2       4 
2            0       6 
2            1       2
```

and want to add a column (value t-1), that contains the value - within the same group - of the "row" a time step earlier:

```
groupId | time | value | value t-1
1            0       2           -
1            1       1           2
1            2       4           1
2            0       6           -
2            1       2           6
```

I imagine the costly part is to search for the preceding row. Somehow it seems like a job for map reduce without a reduction - if this makes sense. But as far as I understand I can't be sure to have all data of the same group on the same worker.

Is Spark the right tool for the job?

*My best alternative solution is to split the file into multiple files (one per group) and just run multiple instances of a python script that sorts and sequentially adds the value t-1 values*

Comment: Are you going to do this to several files? If you just need to fix a single file, do a simple for loop and wait (probably a lot) for it to parse your 3GB of data

Comment: @JBernardo For now I have to do this only once, but there's a chance this will become a more regular use case. The loop is somewhere in the ballpark of 1 to 2 days - and it's just sad to see only one busy core...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the spark's Window function as shown below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq((1,0,2), (1,1,1), (1,2,4), (2,0,6), (2,1,2)).toDF("groupId", "time", "value")

val result = df.withColumn("value_t-1", sum($"value").over(Window.partitionBy("groupId").orderBy("time").rowsBetween(-1,-1)))
```

**Output:**

```
scala> result.show()
+-------+----+-----+---------+
|groupId|time|value|value_t-1|
+-------+----+-----+---------+
|      1|   0|    2|     null|
|      1|   1|    1|        2|
|      1|   2|    4|        1|
|      2|   0|    6|     null|
|      2|   1|    2|        6|
+-------+----+-----+---------+
```

**Python version**:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as func
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,0,2), (1,1,1), (1,2,4), (2,0,6), (2,1,2)], ["groupId", "time", "value"])
>>> result = df.withColumn("value_t-1", func.sum(df.value).over(Window.partitionBy(df.groupId).orderBy(df.time).rowsBetween(-1,-1)))
>>> result.show()
+-------+----+-----+---------+
|groupId|time|value|value_t-1|
+-------+----+-----+---------+
|      1|   0|    2|     null|
|      1|   1|    1|        2|
|      1|   2|    4|        1|
|      2|   0|    6|     null|
|      2|   1|    2|        6|
+-------+----+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks! processed the entire file (9 such cols) in less than 25 minutes on a single machine (8 cores)